# iOS App for targeted audience who are non-employees

Tags: ios, iphone, enterprise, iphone-developer-program, limited-user

**Target Audience:**

An application which is targeted at a specific audience who are not working as employees in a common company or the company publishing the app, but are freelancing end users.

The application is not meant for public use; the target audiences are known and are aware of the application developed for their usage.

**Current Scenario:**

The application is live on the iTunes and being used by the very same target audience.

**Problem Definition:**

I am aware that Apple offers an "Apple Developer Enterprise Program" which can be used by a company for developing apps distributed within that company.

**Questions:**

1. What can be done if the end users are limited and known but not "within the company"?
2. If we use the "Apple Developer Enterprise Program" to publish the next update, how would this affect the developing company as well as the end user?
3. What are the key points to be considered while comparing the Apple Developer Program with the Apple Developer Enterprise Program?
4. How do we notify the end-users about the updates released for the app published through the "Apple Developer Enterprise Program"?

Comment: I don't know of a compliant distribution method that answers question #1.  The other three are addressed at the following link (though perhaps not relevant to your scenario, given the non-enterprise nature of your audience): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH33-SW1

Comment: Create it as an enterprise app. Host the app on a website which you control. Email the intended users with the link to the website so they can install it, adding some sort of logon mechanism to the website if you need to prevent others from installing it.

Comment: Don't the provisioning profiles expire at some point, after which the end users need to install new ones?